# appInjector in component not working

Tags: dependency-injection, angular

I am still struggling with angular 2. I am trying to use the `http` module but I am getting unresolved dependencies. I am using alpha 31. Here is the source of my component:

```
/// <reference path="../typings/angular2/angular2.d.ts" />

import {Component, View} from 'angular2/angular2';
import {Http, httpInjectables} from 'angular2/angular2';

// Annotation section
@Component({
    selector: 'test',
    appInjector: [httpInjectables]
})
@View({
    templateUrl: 'EcoApp/Views/test.html'
})
// Component controller
export class Test2Component {
    name: string;

    constructor(http: Http) {
        this.name = http.toString();
    }
}
```

And this is the first error I'm getting (there are others following it, not listed here):

```
No provider for function (_backend, _defaultOptions) {
        this._backend = _backend;
        this._defaultOptions = _defaultOptions;
      }! (Test2Component -> function (_backend, _defaultOptions) {
        this._backend = _backend;
        this._defaultOptions = _defaultOptions;
      })
STACKTRACE:
Error: null
    at NoBindingError.BaseException (https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.31/angular2.dev.js:7713:25)
    at NoBindingError.AbstractBindingError (https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.31/angular2.dev.js:9595:66)
    at new NoBindingError (https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.31/angular2.dev.js:9613:60)
    at Injector._getByKey (https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.31/angular2.dev.js:27021:21)
    at Injector._getByDependency (https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.31/angular2.dev.js:26979:27)
    at Injector._new (https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.31/angular2.dev.js:26877:68)
    at InjectorInlineStrategy.hydrate (https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.31/angular2.dev.js:26618:31)
    at ElementInjector._reattachInjector (https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.31/angular2.dev.js:28293:39)
    at ElementInjector._hydrateInjector (https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.31/angular2.dev.js:28279:20)
    at ElementInjector.hydrate (https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.31/angular2.dev.js:28263:18)
    BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ angular2.dev.js:20567
    ExceptionHandler.call @ angular2.dev.js:13852
    _errorHandler @ angular2.dev.js:14140
    NgZone._onError @ angular2.dev.js:14079
    errorHandling.onError @ angular2.dev.js:14022
    run @ angular2.dev.js:136
    (anonymous function) @ angular2.dev.js:14036
    zoneBoundFn @ angular2.dev.js:106
    lib$es6$promise$$internal$$tryCatch @ angular2.dev.js:1356
    lib$es6$promise$$internal$$invokeCallback @ angular2.dev.js:1368
    lib$es6$promise$$internal$$publish @ angular2.dev.js:1339
    (anonymous function) @ angular2.dev.js:184
    microtask @ angular2.dev.js:14061
    run @ angular2.dev.js:133
    (anonymous function) @ angular2.dev.js:14036
    zoneBoundFn @ angular2.dev.js:106
    lib$es6$promise$asap$$flush @ angular2.dev.js:1150
```

Answer (score 3):

Ok I have to answer my own question which I discovered based on the link from the answer by @jhadesdev. It appears that `appInjector` has been renamed to `viewInjector`, when I used the latter it worked just fine.

Here's a link to the issue and the revealing post

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/2788#issuecomment-117968971

Thanks everyone

Comment: Here is a working http example in case it's helpful: http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/angular-2.0-and-http